# SSR with PWM for a 9kW heating element

Tags: pwm, heat, three-phase, solid-state-relay

I have rather a silly but urgent question. Do common three phase SSRs come with built in control systems or do they have to be controlled with PWM?

I want to buy [this SSR](https://www.sensata.com/products/relays/solid-state-relays/panel-mount-ac-output-ssrs/53tp-series).

The datasheet mentions it is controlled by 4-32 VDC. Does that mean I only need to provide a signal of different amplitude to control the output power?

I want the SSR to control the output of a heating element from my energy management system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a safety warning: unlike the classic relays, SSRs have a significant leakage current (your chosen model has up to 10mA), which may not be deadly but it may be shocking or painful. Don't assume because an SSR is off that there is no current on its outputs, just turn the related mechanical switch or fuse off if working with the related wiring!

> Do common three phase SSRs come with built in control systems or do
> they have to be controlled with PWM?

SSRs, or Solid State Relays, are merely relatively slow switches which turn a high power load on or off with a very low control power, much like the classic mechanical relays, only with shorter turn on and off times (though they may intentionally delay their switch action by up to half a cycle, or up to 10 milliseconds, to achieve zero-volt-switching or ZVS, which is about the same amount of time as mechanical relays), no switching noise, but a higher voltage drop on their output and thus higher losses. This is regarding SSRs using SCRs or TRIACs specifically for AC power, there are SSRs which use MOSFETS or possibly IGBTs and can be used in DC power switching as well. 
So, you can imagine them like mechanical relays in their speed and function, for most purposes, in order to understand what they are. 
The only "control system" most of them have is either all 3 phases are on, or they are off. Thus they are controlled with a **simple DC signal** to turn them **on**, or no signal which turns or leaves them **off**. 
The "signal" merely needs to be of sufficient voltage and current to turn them on (in your case, a voltage ranging from 4V to 32V **DC**, as in direct current, no PWM, and a current of at least 19mA). 
PWM signal is not used simply because of the nature of their main elements - SCRs, or Silicon Controlled Rectifiers, which merely follow the 50/60Hz power cycle and which can't be turned on or off more than 50/60 times per second in a typical control circuit.

> The datasheet mentions it is controlled by 4-32 VDC. Does that mean I
> only need to provide a signal of different amplitude to control the
> output power?

No, that simply means anything from 4V to 32V will turn it on. Whether it's 4V or 32V, it will be completely turned on just the same. The range of voltages simply means that at least 4V is needed to turn it on, and that up to 32V is acceptable and will not damage its control input, so you don't have to worry if your control logic runs on 5V, 12V or 24V.

PWM is hardly, if ever, used with heating systems because they are very laggy by nature and need typically from a **few seconds** to a **few minutes** (or even tens of minutes, and even hours for larger spaces) to show a temperature rise once they're on, depending what they're heating up/what they're in contact with or what the heating medium is (water or oil, for example) and what the volume of the heated medium is.

Instead, the term and the technique of **power cycling** is used with heaters, and it refers to turning the heater on for a few seconds or minutes, and then turning it off for a few seconds or minutes. 
This is because whether you use a higher frequency PWM with, for example, a 30% duty cycle, or you use power cycling with 3 seconds on and 7 seconds off (or 3 minutes on and 7 minutes off, and so on with larger volumes), the end result, the given amount of heat, will be the same, and if something can be done with lower speed, it makes things easier. 
If a form of "PWM" is used with AC heaters, it is done with SCRs or TRIACs which use a portion of the 50/60Hz AC cycle to control the amount of power.

But the typical, higher frequency PWM (few hundred Hz to few or tens of kHz) that you're referring to in your question is not used in high power heating systems also because it would require power rectifiers which would additionally waste power (besides the power elements like IGBTs), it would add unnecessary circuit complexity, and it would unnecessarily generate EMI (electromagnetic interference). It would also greatly worsen the power factor if PF correction circuit (additional complexity and power waste) is not used.

If you have read all this and come this far, here is a little hint to turn your SSR heat waste into no waste: if possible, attach your SSR's heatsink side to the body of the tank (if there is one), whether it's water or oil inside, to transfer the wasted heat to the medium that you are heating up. The metallic surface of the tank would have to be exposed for this and you would have to take precautions regarding electricity coming into contact with any surfaces. 
If the heated area includes the air and the room in which the SSR is located, then a heatsink onto which the SSR is attached will simply add the heat to the room and make it utilized instead of wasted.

Comment: I am in your debt for actually clarifying many interesting points. The reason I need PWM is that my energy system tells me how much energy is being fed to the grid system. Sometimes I have 500 W available and sometimes I have 8kW available. The idea was to use a thyristor but the energy system I have has only relay control available which I can turn on and off fast to control the output power of the heating system. If I simply turn on it completely, the system will draw the rest of the energy from the grid which is not possible.

Comment: You have solar panels on your house and you want to utilize them for heating as much as possible?

Comment: Yes, I have a solar system, I also have a smart logger which monitors how much energy inverters are generating. I also connected an energy meter which measures how much energy is being fed to the grid. I want to only use the surplus energy from our solar system. I have 3 phase heating element which I have to still buy, this does not come with a control so I have to make my own power control system. My datalogger company told that I can control the power with PWM but I am only familiar with thyristors, I am unable to speak what is SCR or triac.

Comment: @Smrtngy SCR or TRIAC is a "thyristor". Since you are already starting with DC, it should be easier to implement PWM directly from it, but after it was turned to AC you need more circuits and you're wasting more energy (including on your inverter) which could all be bypassed with solar panel DC straight to PWM into heaters, but it would take a skilled electronics person to figure it all out and connected it together.

Comment: Yes, now that I have AC power available I only have to use the solution with a solid-state relay. Can you please mention how much in percentage are the losses? I only thought that I just needed a circuit breaker and an SSR. Can you please confirm that I can use the SSR, I have mentioned in my question for controlling the output power?

Comment: @Smrtngy You CAN use the SSR, but it will not give you the amount of control you need. It is better to use a PWM "chopper circuit" which works in similar fashion to electronic PF correction circuit, using high-frequency PWM and then filtering the high-frequency out. Its losses could be similar to other methods, but you would have a fine/detailed and fast control over the power output.

Comment: @Smrtngy A solar inverter typically has at least 1-2% and up to 5-6% power loss, SSR about 0.33% in your case (surprisingly low), a rectifier bridge would be similar to SSR loss, high-frequency "chopper" (3-phase) also similar to SSR... Percentage-wise, these are not high losses. Your greatest loss would come in the form of poor power factor, where panels and inverter would need to feed up to 30-50% more power than what you get into your heaters, also increasing the wiring losses.

Comment: I am thankful for your time, just have one last question. I do not desire a specific accuracy. I would also prefer to make steps higher. For example, I want to turn on at 500 watts up to 9kW with a step of 100 watts or 500 watts.

Comment: @Smrtngy High-frequency chopping using IGBTs and filters would be the best solution for reliable control. The much simpler and cheaper control would be using SCRs, but I can't predict how would the inverter react to full-load, low-frequency (50/60/100/120Hz) pulses. Also, you would get much higher (3-4 times) efficiency if you used a heat-pump instead: for every 1kW of electricity you would get about 3-4kW of equivalent heat, meaning your 9kW heater could be replaced with a 2-3kW heat-pump.

Comment: @Smrtngy By the way, if my comments are helpful/useful, you can upvote them too.

Comment: They are helpful. But I don't find a specific option to upvote each comment. There is only a flag option available. Perhaps I am a new member and my privileges are limited. I can only accept the answer as correct but cannot upvote

Answer (score 4):

The voltage range means you can use a range of voltages, in this case 4-32V to control the relay. It's purely on/off, there's no power control, you can do this yourself using PWM. Make sure you take a note of the input current required to turn the relay on, so you drive it properly, and also the time to turn on/off.

For something like the D53TP25D, it needs 19mA at 4V, which might be more than your controller can put out, so you could use a buffer/op amp to get enough drive current. It takes 1/2 a 50Hz cycle to turn on/off, so perhaps PWM at 1Hz or less might be suitable.